# How to calculate in this JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem in jQuery in html. Just need some changes in calculation, below are my codes All result will be calculated in one field as I did

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).on('keyup','input.expenses','input.deductions',function(){
          $expenses = $(this).parents('tr').find('.expenses');
          $deductions = $(this).parents('tr').find('.deductions');
          $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('tr').find('#total');
          $expenseTotal.val('0');
          $.each($expenses,function(index,object){    
            if($(object).val()!='')
            {
         $expenseTotal.val(parseInt($expenseTotal.val())+parseInt($(object).val()));
            }
          })
        });
      </script>
    </pre>
                    
    
        <   <tbody>';
    
                foreach($data as $d)
                {
                    print '<tr>
                    <td>'.$d["staff_name"].'</td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="txtid[]" value="'.$d["id"].'">
                        <input type="text" name="txtbasic[]" class="form-control expenses">
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtallowance[]" class="form-control expenses"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtsocso[]" class="form-control deductions"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtkwsp[]" class="form-control deductions"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="total" name="txttotal[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>';
                }
                print '</tbody>
```

Existing result

txttotal = txtbasic + txtallowance

The result i need is

txttotal = txtbasic + txtallowance - txtsocso - txtkwsp

Then display the result on key up, Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few logic/structure issues with your code so I'll first explain each of them, then at the bottom you can find the resulting code

### KeyUp event wrong syntax

To be sure you listed to the `keyup` even on all fields, you need to separate with the comma within the same parameter, so instead of being

`on('keyup','input.expenses','input.deductions',function()`

It must be

`on('keyup','input.expenses, input.deductions',function()`

### Using ID in loop

You're using a  `foreach` loop to generate your table rows. So you'll have a lot of rows with the same content, which is fine. However, for the last cell of your row, you're using `id="total"` which is wrong because in any HTML page there can only be 1 element with a unique id. With your code, you will have all rows having the same ID for the last `td`.

So you need to remove the ID and use a class instead.

From

`input type="text" id="total" name="txttotal[]" class="form-control"`

You go to

`input type="text" name="txttotal[]" class="form-control total"`

### Correctly loop the elements

Currently your code only loops the `.expenses` so the  `txtbasic` and `txtallowance` values. You also need to loop the `deductions` to obtain `txtsocso` and  `txtkwsp`

### Final Code

#### Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).on('keyup', 'input.expenses, input.deductions', function () {

        var total = 0;
        // Adding txtbasic and txtallowance
        $expenses = $(this).parents('tr').find('.expenses');
        $.each($expenses, function (index, object) {
            var val = parseInt($(object).val())
            if(!isNaN(val) && val) {
                total += parseInt($(object).val());
            }
        });

        // Adding txtsocso and txtkwsp
        $deductions = $(this).parents('tr').find('.deductions');
        $.each($deductions, function (index, object) {
            var val = parseInt($(object).val())
            if(!isNaN(val) && val) {
                total -= parseInt($(object).val());
            }
        });

        // Updating the Total
        $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('tr').find('.total');
        $expenseTotal.val(total)
    });
</script>
```

#### HTML TR Code

```
        <tr>
            <td>'.$d["staff_name"].'</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="txtid[]" value="'.$d["id"].'">
                <input type="text" name="txtbasic[]" class="form-control expenses">
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtallowance[]" class="form-control expenses"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtsocso[]" class="form-control deductions"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtkwsp[]" class="form-control deductions"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txttotal[]" class="form-control total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
``
```

Comment: wow, good explanation. Appreciate it, anyway how if i want the 
total = ( txtbasic + txtallowance ) - ( txtsocso + txtkwsp )

Comment: ok found it, i've just change + to - of total $deductions..tqvm

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the deduction on $deductions. If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as the accepted one for future readers

Comment: anyway i've got one more issue..the txtkwsp actually a percentage not amount like txtbasic,txtallowance,txtsocso..did u have idea if want the total was minus txtkwsp (percentage)

Comment: totalkwsp = txtkwsp / 100 * (txtbasic+txtallowance)